# String not being passed to next view controller from prepareForSegue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have a `push segue` on my StoryBoard which is named `toGuestVC`.

I use that to segue to the next `ViewController` in my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method like so:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let username = followUsernameArray[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: SG_TO_GUEST_VIEW_CONTROLLER, sender: username)
}
```

Then in my `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == SG_TO_GUEST_VIEW_CONTROLLER {
        if let nextVC = segue.destination as? GuestCollectionVC, let sender = sender as? String {
            print("PRINTING NEXT VC: \(nextVC)") //This prints out the memory address. Not sure if this is what you meant by print nextVC.
            nextVC.guestUser = sender
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason this line in my `prepareForSegue` is not running:

> `nextVC.guestUser = sender.username`

When I try to print out the value `guestUser` in my nextViewController the value of `guestUser` is `nil`. But when I print out the value of sender in my `prepareForSegue` method it is not `nil`.

So is my `sender` value not being passed to the next `ViewController`? I can't find a solution to this problem any ideas?

`GuestCollectionVC` Implementation:

```
import UIKit
import Parse

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class GuestCollectionVC: UICollectionViewController {

var guestUser: String!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("PRINTING SELF IN GuestCollectionVC: \(self)")
    loadPosts()
}

    func loadPosts() {
        //Load posts query
        let query = PFQuery(className: PF_POSTS_CLASS)
        query.limit = postCount
        //Getting error here below this comment when I use guestUser since it is nil
        query.whereKey(PF_POSTS_USERNAME_COLUMN, equalTo: guestUser)
        query.findObjectsInBackground { (result: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                if let result = result {

                    self.uuidOfPosts.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.imageArrayOfPFFIle.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)

                    for postObject in result {
                        if let uuid = postObject[PF_POSTS_UUID_COLUMN] as? String, let pic = postObject[PF_POSTS_PIC_COLUMN] as? PFFile {
                            self.uuidOfPosts.append(uuid)
                            self.imageArrayOfPFFIle.append(pic)
                        }
                    }
                    self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                }
            }else if error != nil {
                print("ERROR FROM GUEST COLLECTION VC FROM loadPosts FUNCTION: \(error?.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So this is my implementation in the GuestViewController. In my `loadPosts` method where I used the variable `guestUser` I am getting the error:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: What is the value of `username`?

Comment: It is a string. So based on which row they select it will grab it from that array.

Comment: Looks like `guestUser` property you trying to set later replaced in some `GuestCollectionVC` load methods, probably in `viewDidLoad`. Show us `GuestCollectionVC` implementation please.

Comment: @ShadowOf Ok sure I will update my post.

Comment: @ShadowOf I have updated my answer.

Comment: Your code as shown should work. It have few issues, like you didn't called `super.viewDidLoad`, but I can't find why `guestUser` can be `nil`. Mistake is somewhere deeper. Probably, you created another segue, just unnamed action segue from cell to `GuestCollectionVC`? Then "toGuestVC" is just fake duplicated segue, real error happends in unnamed segue due to uninitialized hidden controller created. Check your storyboard please

Comment: @ShadowOf I tried to look on my StoryBoard for duplicate segue or unused ones, I didn't find any. Still not sure what the issue is.

Comment: @1290 you can 1) unmark this question as closed 2) comment `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGuestVC", sender: self)` line and tell us what happend

Comment: When I uncommented it: I get this error: `This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.` which is a parse specific thing so I now have to fix that issue as well... lol

Comment: New issue appeared when you *comment* line I asked or when you *uncomment* after commenting? What was happend when you commented it? Error message usually means that you performing multiple fetch operations at one time. Please, make following steps: **1)** add `super.viewDidLoad()` line at start of any `override func viewDidLoad()` used in your project; **2)** add line `print(nextVC)` in `prepareForSegue` method; **3)** add line `print(self)` in `viewDidLoad` method of `GuestCollectionVC`. After that, update code here to actual used, run app, click some cell and show us *full* console output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123747/discussion-between-1290-and-shadow-of).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From console printing

> PRINTING NEXT VC: "InstagramClone.GuestCollectionVC: 0x7a6c5cc0"
>
> PRINTING SELF IN GuestCollectionVC: "InstagramClone.GuestCollectionVC: 0x7a6c5100"

it's now obvious that hidden unexpected instance of `GuestCollectionVC` was created. So, there are different errors occurs depending on order of this two objects invoke their `viewDidLoad` method (can be any order). Also there are can be other errors in `nextVC` `viewDidLoad` method, but this is other story for other question.

You got this problems because you created **action** segue, that works automatically on cell click (hidden view controller created), and at the same time you are perform this segue in code, creating second controller `nextVC`.

To solve issue, you should find and remove that segue and add new one, not **action** segue from some element of your view controller, but "empty" segue between view controllers. To create segue of this type you should select first view controller, hold "control" key and start dragging to next view controller **from yellow square on top of first view controller** (that symbol controller itself), choose "show", and set identifier.

Comment: Oh ok! It worked now. That is what I originally thought. I might have created the segues incorrectly.

Answer (score -1):

Since I don't have the full context of the values within your `tableView` method I can only speculate. That said, the sender you're passing in should be the view controller:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGuestVC", sender: username)
```

You're passing in a value called `username` which looks to be a string value? It should be something like:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGuestVC", sender: self)
```

where `self` is your view controller. If you're passing in a string value to `sender` then in your `prepareForSegue` method then `sender` does not have a property called `username` sender actually *is* `username`. Therefore you should pass the value elsewhere:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
    if let nextVC = segue.destination as? GuestCollectionVC {
        nextVC.guestUser = followUsernameArray[indexPath.row]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But I do not believe I am calling `destination` on the String value of `sender`. I am calling `destination` on the `UIStoryboardSegue` object (segue). Correct me if I interpreted your answer incorrectly. But I will try to replace the string value with self.

Comment: Right. Brain fart and I edited my answer. You get the idea anyhow.

Comment: Ok so I used `self` and updated both of my methods in my post but it is still giving me `nil.`

Comment: I also have this declaration of `guestUser` in my next view controller: `var guestUser: String!`

Comment: So wouldn't I have to call: `performSegue(withIdentifier: "toGuestVC", sender: indexPath)`

Comment: No, the `sender` parameter is meant to indicate the UI element that triggers the segue. Your view controller is what ultimately triggers the segue and hence is the sender.

Comment: Oh ok let me try that.

Comment: @1290 please stop modify `sender` parameter. You can analyze this later, this is not the real titled problem, your code from very first question version should work, you *can* pass `NSString` (and `AnyObject`) in this parameter, though it's antipattern a bit. Problem is somewhere deeper.

Comment: Finally! It is working now. Why is it bad to send a String as a sender to `preapreToSegue`? I have done that before and it worked previously.

Comment: @ShadowOf Yeah I see exactly what you are saying. I should be able to pass anything to the `sender` parameter and the problem is somewhere deeper like you stated previously where I might have a fake unused segue. I will try to look into that now.